# How do I define a variable for use everywhere

Tags: c#

According to below code , after getting some value (newrev,newreview) and putting in the variable, I need to put them in the label ("some text"+newrev). But I have problem (newrev) does not exist in current context.

```
Label1.Text = "Review Number:" + newReview + "(for preparing of Rev." + newrev+")";

protected void ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

    var x = ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue;

    var MaxRev = (from rev in _DataContext.tblTransmittalls
                  where rev.DocID.ToString() == ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue
                  select  rev.REV).Max();

    if (MaxRev == null)
    {
        var newRev = 0;

    }

    else
    {

        var newRev = Convert.ToInt32(MaxRev) + 1;

    }

    var MaxReview = (from rev in _DataContext.tblFiles
                  where (rev.DocId.ToString()==ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue)&&   
                        (rev.Rev.ToString()==MaxRev)
                  select rev.Review).Max();

    if (MaxReview == null)
    {
        var newReview = 1;
    }

    else
    {    
        var newReview = Convert.ToInt32(MaxReview) + 1;
    }

    Label1.Text = "Review Number:" + newReview + "(for preparing of Rev." + newrev+")";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried formatting your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `newRev` outside the `if` statement.

```
int newrev;
if(MaxRev == null)
    newRev = 0;
else
    newRev = Convert.ToInt32(MaxRev) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `newRev` and `newReview` in the begining of your function like this:

```
protected void ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
    int newRev;
    int newReview;
```

Then when you want to use them, instead of writing `var newReview = ...` (which declares a new variable) remove the `var`... e.g.:

```
if (MaxReview == null)
{
    newReview = 1;
}
```

**The difference:**
Every variable that is declared has a ***[Scope](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx)***, which  determines its visibility to the rest of a program. In your case, the `newReview` is known *only inside the `if` statement*, so when you try to reference it outside, it no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

C# is not JavaScript, you should use less "var"...
You are defining your newRev inside

```
if (MaxRev == null)
{
    var newRev = 0;
}
```

define it here

```
protected void ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
     var newRev = 0;
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're declaring newRev within various if statements, declare it at the outer level:

```
int newRev;
if (MaxRev == null)
{
    newRev = 0;

}
```